# In Salesforce, Can we send mass email to records which are not in Salesforce through configuration

Tags: send-email

I have a CSV file containing 900 records with email and id field.i want to send email to all the 900 records.These records are not present in Salesforce org.
Is there any way through configuration in Salesforce.

Comment: Are you wiling to load the records in salesforce in a custom object? you can configure workflow email alerts for the object and send out email based on email field.

Comment: i am not going to store the records in Custom object.